# Merging two models into the single view in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@model .Models.somemodel1. this is one  view data.

@model .Models.somemodel2. this is another view data.
```

How can I merge both models into a single view?

Answer (score 3):

Create a viewmodel wrapper class then use it in a view. Read [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

```
public class MyViewModel
{
 public SomeModel1 someModel1{get;set;}
 public SomeModel2 someModel2{get;set;}
}
```

In your View

```
 @model MyViewModel

 <div>Model.someModel1.Property</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanations. When using ViewModel, I cannot retrieve Display Names typed on Domain Model. If I have to define them on DomainModel as well what if I use several viewmodels from the same Domain model? In that case I have to define this as `[Display(Name = "Name")]` multiple times. Is that true?

Comment: @Christof, Hope you have defined `[Display(Name = "Name")]` in the view model object you bound to your view. If its not working, please feel free to ask a new question in stackoverflow, so it would be easy for us to see the code and understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048530/is-it-possible-to-reuse-the-dataannotations-in-viewmodel/31048731?noredirect=1#comment50118981_31048731) question pls?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tuple

**In View**

```
@model  Tuple<Model1, Model2>

// You can access the model values like
@Model.Item1.FirstName
@Model.Item2.Mark
```

**Controller**

```
Model1 m1 = new Model1();
Model2 m2= new Model2();
var tuple = new Tuple<Model1,Model2>(m1,m2);
return View(tuple);
```

For more details

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)