# Is it possible to reuse the DataAnnotations in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, domain-model

In my MVC application, I defined the DataAnnotations in the domain models. Although the DataAnnotations properties as Display, etc. can be retrieved when using Domain model, they cannot be retrieved when using the same properties on ViewModel and using this ViewModel. I think it is not seem to good to define the DataAnnotations in ViewModel again. So, is it possible or which way should I follow?

**Domain Model:**

```
public class Issue
{
    [Key] 
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Project Number")]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Issue Definition")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //... removed for brevity

    //Navigation Properties:
    public virtual ICollection<FileAttachment> FileAttachments { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class IssueViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    //... removed for brevity

    //Navigation Properties:
    public virtual ICollection<FileAttachment> FileAttachments { get; set; }      
}
```

Comment: You can use a proxy class to reuse data annotations – this was done to allow manual annotations on automatically generated model types.

Comment: You need to define them in the view model. But why would you ever have a `[Display]` attribute (which as an attribute specific to a view) in a domain model anyway?

Comment: @Richard: Could you post an example pls?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi Stephane. But when I define them in the ViewModel, I need to reuse some of them again (assuming that I will need to create several ViewModel using the same domain model). So, is it logical?

Comment: If your creating several view models for the same domain model, its suggests they might be for different purposes, so therefore may have different validation requirement anyway. But you can always begin with a ViewModelBase with common properties (and decorated with attributes) and then create create your (say) EditViewModel by inheriting it

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are right. Do you mean such a way as indicated on Farhad's answer with "ViewModelBase"?

Comment: @StephenMuecke **1)** If I define the data annotations in the ViewModel, I think I do not need to define them in domain model as well. Is that true?

Comment: @StephenMuecke **2)** If so, the domain model also affects Database as because I use Entity Framework Code First. In that case the required fields will be updated as nullable in the database. Of course the data will be validated with model validation and the required fields cannot be null before sending the database, but I am not sure if it is normal? Any idea?

Comment: May or may not be necessary depending on what you are doing (but having a `[Display]` attribute in a domain model does not makes sense). I don't use EF so bit hard to comment on your case

Comment: Ok, I moved [Display] attributes from domain to viewmodel. On the other hand, [Required] attribute is vital for both domain and viewmodel and I think I should use them for domain and viewmodel. Any idea?

Comment: You're right. Required is both for database operations (means not null) and view (validation). (Like length, etc.)

Comment: @ilter Thanks a lot. As far as I understood, as the domain classes directly affects the database in EF, we should use the [Required], [MaxLength], etc. fields (except from [Display] attribute, this is only for viewmodel) in domain model. On the other hand, we should also use these attributes in viewmodel so that we can check the validity of data in the Controller before sending database. Are all of that true?

Comment: Pretty much, you got the idea ;) I suggest you to take some time and read about some articles on EF and DataAnnotations, in order to get the whole idea. Google will help :)

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new  **buddy** class which holds all metadata about properties and class.

```
public partial class IssueMetadata
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Project Number")]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Issue Definition")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then, we must tell the MVC Framework about the buddy class through the `MetadataType` attribute, which takes the type of the buddy class as its argument. Buddy classes must be defined in the same namespace and 
must also be `partial` classes.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(IssueMetadata))]
public partial class IssueViewModel
{
      //...

      public int ProjectID { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }

      //...
}

[MetadataType(typeof(IssueMetadata))]
public partial class Issue
{
      [Key] 
      public int ID { get; set; }

      public int ProjectID { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }

      //... removed for brevity

      //Navigation Properties:
      public virtual ICollection<FileAttachment> FileAttachments { get; set; }
}
```

***Additional note:***
If `IssueMetadata` and `Issue` (or `IssueViewModel`) classes located in different assemblies, then you can associate classes with their buddy class in runtime, like that:

```
public class AssociatedMetadataConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMetadatas()
    {
        RegisterPairOfTypes(typeof(Issue), typeof(IssueMetadata));
        RegisterPairOfTypes(typeof(IssueViewModel), typeof(IssueMetadata));
    }

    private static void RegisterPairOfTypes(Type mainType, Type buddyType)
    {
        AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider typeDescriptionProvider 
          = new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(mainType, buddyType);

        TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(typeDescriptionProvider, mainType);
    }
}
```

And, just call this static method in `global.asax`:

```
AssociatedMetadataConfig.RegisterMetadatas();
```

Comment: Selam Farhad. Could you post the full example containing domain and viwmodel classes pls? Because I have never use metadata and not any idea about it :(

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev, That is a good way to solve the issue :) That way, can we create a general MetadataType and use it in all our Model Classes? I mean, the fields in the meta class have to be used in the Model Classes?

Comment: @Christof I updtaed my answer. You just need additional class.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Thanks  a lot for reply. The last "Additional note" is also a must to apply this method.

Comment: @Christof I have forgot to add "SALAM" to the my previous comment. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

@StephenMuecke is right. DomainModel attributes and ViewModel attributes are different and you can use them seperately in your models. But I would use inheretence in this case, if I were you. You can create a Partial class for ViewModel and inherit your DomainModel from this ViewModel class.

Like:

```
public class IssueVM
{
    [Key] 
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Project Number")]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Issue Definition")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //... removed for brevity

    //Navigation Properties:
    public virtual ICollection<FileAttachment> FileAttachments { get; set; }
}

public class IssueDM : IssueVM
{
    // Other Fields
}
```

That way you have a base class of ViewModel (less fields) and a larger class with more fields for DB operations. Your ViewModel data annotation attributes are also inherited in your DomainClass that way.

I don't claim that this is the best way, but I'am using this and works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems to be similar to the answer of Farhad as you said. On the other hand, as I define my domain models in Data Layer and define viewmodels on Web Layer, it seems to be good to use the metadata. Voted+

Comment: I got you. Of course, what @FarhadJabiyev offered seems like a more elegant way. I just wanted to offer a simpler solution. His is the best answer so far :)